# Spring Cloud Discrovery Eureka - Returns Localhost instead the hostname it is located

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-netflix, spring-cloud-config

I am using Spring Cloud Eureka Server and Config Server, as Discovery First, and my problem is:

When a service registry it self in the eureka server the Config Server URL it returns is ***http://LOCALHOST:8888*** intead of the ***http://{HOST_NAME}}:8888*** and them all the other services hosted in another servers cannot find its configuration.

Log line:

> Fetching config from server at: http://localhost:8888

Is there any configuration I can do to fix it?

The application.yml of configuration server is like that:

```
server:
  port: 8888

spring:
  application:
    name: configserver
  profiles:
    active: native
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        native:
          searchLocations: /opt/config_dir

eureka:
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://10.111.22.33:8761/eureka,http://10.111.33.44:8761/eureka
```

The config client bootstrap.yml is like this:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: show-service
  profiles:
    active: dev
  cloud:
    discovery:
      enabled: true

eureka:
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://10.111.22.33:8761/eureka,http://10.111.33.44:8761/eureka
```

Comment: I don't know, what does your configuration look like?

Comment: I added the configuration

Comment: Which version are u using?

Comment: The default is localhost:8888. Somehow I feel it could not be getting the urls from eureka.

Comment: I am using Spring cloud Fincley.RC2

Comment: is it possible for u to post a sample on github?

Comment: Also , can you change the port of your config Server. Run it on port no 8889 and see if localhost:8889 is picked up?

Answer (score 2):

By default  Discovery First Bootstrap is disabled. You are missing few properties in the config client application - to enable using discovery to look up the config server URL and your config server name (service-id).

```
spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      discovery:
       enabled: true
       service-id: configserver
```

More: https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/multi/multi__spring_cloud_config_client.html#discovery-first-bootstrap

Comment: Thanks a lot! I followed an old guide and use `spring.cloud.discovery.enabled=true` instead, which doesn't work in newer springboot

Answer (score 0):

i solved this issue by deploy my project
mvn deploy
hope this solve your problem